# How to use GAMMA function _xlfn.GAMMA?

Tags: microsoft-excel

Microsoft website has [an introduction](http://office.microsoft.com/en-sg/excel-help/gamma-function-HA102753277.aspx) on GAMMA function.

I could download it and have a look, it's a ".xlsx" file and the formula is shown as `=_xlfn.GAMMA(2.5)`.

[image]

However, when I create a new excel ".xlsx" file, I can't use it, neither by write formula as `=_xlfn.GAMMA(2.5)" or "=GAMMA(2.5)`.
[image]

Did I missed something? Is there some library I shall register, like using Solver function?

---

Clarification

@dave-rook is right.

I'm using Excel 2007. The msdn page says "GAMMA" function applies to Excel 2013, so the problem is the version.

Comment: What version of Excel are you using?

Comment: youre right the function isnt included with the workbook. it does work on the embed spreadsheet on the web, but its not anywhere to find within the downloaded file itself.

Comment: is there some library can do that? i know that excel can have plugin's..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In excel 2003 and up you can use

```
=EXP(GAMMALN(value))
```

For all positive values

Answer (score 0):

If `GAMMALN` is not available under your language settings, you may need to be using the following formula:

```
=GAMMA.LN(EXP(value))
```

Comment: This is better as a comment perhaps